# Cookie fails when login to Odoo from PHP

Tags: php, cookies, odoo, xml-rpc

I followed the steps of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39609130/login-to-odoo-from-external-php-system/39617759#answer-39617759) to manage login to Odoo with PHP. The response from XML-RPC is fine and I get back a *session_id*. *$response* looks like that:

```
Array
(
    [jsonrpc] => 2.0
    [result] => Array
        (
            [session_id] => 64c429e748142d0fbcecfe71f6701bf416b9efd4
            ...
        )
)
```

But setting a cookie using this session_id doesn't work, I'm still not logged into Odoo:

```
setcookie('session_id', $response['result']['session_id']);
```

I also tried without success using Javascript:

```
echo '<script>document.cookie="session_id=' . $response['result']['session_id'] . '";</script>';
```

What is going wrong with my cookies?

**UPDATE**

I now moved the code to set the cookie directly on the Odoo domain, I can't run PHP there so I set the cookie via Javascript calling [loginbycookie?id=xxx](https://matter-11-0-20200529-1143810.dev.odoo.com/loginbycookie?id=c07900ddf529e70d1e1a80fc6791e590ff07027f):

```
(function() {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
    const id = params.get('id');
    if (id) {
        console.log("set cookie: session_id="+id);
        document.cookie='session_id='+id;
        console.log(document.cookie);
    } })();
```

I successfully receive the id, but when printing `document.cookie`, it doesn't exist. Instead Inspectors Cookies tab shows a cookie with a different `session_id` and with parameter `HttpOnly=true`. So it seems to get overwritten by Odoo. Anything I can do to make the cookie persistent?

Comment: For example, you can try use setcookie via php.

Comment: Thanks, but using PHP setcookie() doesn't work neither.

Comment: I don't know what oodo is at all, but does it live on the same exact domain as this PHP and/or JS code? Or is it a subdomain or a completely different domain?

Comment: I ran the login and setcookie code on a completely different domain, but I use the $domain parameter with the Odoo domain name. So probably that's the problem, I have to set the cookie on the Odoo domain?

Comment: Your JavaScript is probably running _after_ Odoo runs, so the session already exists. From the link that you provided earlier, you are supposed to redirect to a page that only has this JS, nothing else, and that JS should further redirect on to the main Odoo app. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: Maybe there is some CSRF token

Comment: I don't see any CSRF token, how could I detect them? Most probably it's the issue that @ChrisHaas comments: I included the JavaScript on a regular Odoo page so probably the session already exists. I have a Odoo Online account and there seems to be no way to run the JavaScript on odoo.com before Odoo itself runs.